# iOS 9 cancelLocalNotification problems

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, notifications

I've had an app on the App Store for over a year now which uses `UILocalNotification`s to act as reminders. The `UILocalNotification`s use the `repeatInterval`, set to `NSCalendarUnitMinute`, to keep reminding the user of whatever they wanted to be reminded of.

Everything was fine with the app when building against iOS 7/8 but now that I've started to build it against iOS 9 I'm having epic issues using `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification: notification]` to stop previously scheduled notifications.

I've checked the number of notifications in `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications]` before and after cancelling a notification to verify that the count does get decremented, but when it comes round to the time that the notification would have hit its `repeatInterval` the notification cheerily pops up its head to haunt me...

I've tried all sorts of things... cancelling individual notifications, `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications]`, `[UIApplication sharedApplication].scheduledLocalNotifications = [NSArray array]` but nothing was doing the trick at all...

A number of times I thought I'd solved the problem but then it would keep rearing its head, generally on older notifications I'd scheduled, though always seemed fine on ones I'd just recently setup.

Just now I managed to get rid of a lingering, un-cancellable notification by force quitting the app after an attempt to cancel it... which is hardly an elegant solution for end users other than myself...

Has anyone else had these kinds of issues with local notifications, possibly specifically those that are setup to auto-repeat?

For the sake of it I'll reference [this similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24659103/cancellocalnotification-doesnt-seem-to-work/33220976#33220976) which could technically be called a duplicate but I'm posting this new question as the other one isn't getting any interest and needs my somewhat different situation to be described and solved! (PS if you get this question closed as a duplicate I will cry.. and no one wants to see that, right?)

Comment: Out of curiosity: can you reset repeatInterval to 0 and set fireDate to some distant future before cancelling the notification?

Comment: The thought crossed my mind but as far as I know you can't change a local notification, rather you have to cancel and reschedule it...

Comment: Is there any progress on the subject? I've been struggling with this problem for several months now.

Comment: I've not made any more progress than what's listed here. I've been using the dev version of my app myself and it's working fine so pretty sure that the force quitting solution I outline works but I've not pushed it out to my users yet, partly because I'm worried it won't actually work and end up breaking the app for everyone when I don't have any pressing issue to send out an updated build!